# Materialize CSS remove disabled input field not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm using materialize css and I have problem I want to remove the disabled in input field when I pressed the button edit account and by the way in my code in jquery that I will show below. I already tried `.prop()`, `.removeAttr()`, `.removeProp()` but still it doesn't remove the disabled in the field.

I have this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submithidden").hide();

  $("#editbutton").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#fname").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#submithidden").show();
    $("#editbutton").hide();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post"  id="editaccount">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s4">
           <input id="fname" name="firstname" value="Sample Name" disabled type="text" class="center validate">
           <label>First Name</label>
        </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
    <div id="submithidden">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large grey" id="editaccount">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="editbutton" class="btn grey darken-1">Edit Account</button>
                        
    </form>
```

Comment: Your code works fine except you forgot to add semicolon `;` at the end. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hqpsqzao/)

Comment: i tried to put semicolon at the end but when i tried it in my code still it doesnt remove i dont know if the problem is in materializecss or not

Comment: Sir, please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hqpsqzao/) link

Comment: ya i checked it already and also i tried to put materializecss in external resources it works there but i dont know why when i tried it to my work it doesn't even removing the disabled? is there anything else that may cause the problem?

Comment: It is impossible to say what might be affecting it without looking at your code.

Comment: i just tried to copied the code in jsfiddle to my js file and view my source code in browser and it reads the file . but still it doesn't remove the disabled

Comment: not working for me as well, in case of cheked attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .prop like

```js
var disableSelection = function(){
    $("#elementId").prop("disabled", true);    
};

var enableSelection = function(){
    $("#elementId").prop("disabled", false);
};
```

For more information, see .prop() vs .attr().